# Como inserir um array em uma variável?

Tags: python, array, while

Percebendo que tem muito código repetitivo resolvi automatizar criando um looping de leitura das células do meu arquivo excel.

```
#row cell fixa para o horario
rows = ts[1].rows
cells = rows[1].cells
#Segunda 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[3]
t1cell13 = cell.paragraphs
t1cell13 = str(t1cell13[0].text.encode("utf-8"))
t1cell13 = unicode(t1cell13, "utf-8")
print t1cell13
w_sheet.write(8,10, t1cell13, style)
a1 = t1cell13

#terça 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[4]
t1cell14 = cell.paragraphs
t1cell14 = str(t1cell14[0].text.encode("utf-8"))
t1cell14 = unicode(t1cell14, "utf-8")
w_sheet.write(9,10, t1cell14), style)
a2 = t1cell14

#Quarta 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[5]
t1cell15 = cell.paragraphs
t1cell15 = str(t1cell15[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
t1cell15 = unicode(t1cell15, "utf-8")
w_sheet.write(t1cell15, style)
a3 = t1cell15

#quinta 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[6]
t1cell16 = cell.paragraphs
print str(t1cell16[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
w_sheet.write(11,10, str(t1cell16[0].text), style)
a4 = str(t1cell16[0].text.encode('utf-8'))

#sexta 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[7]
t1cell17 = cell.paragraphs
print str(t1cell17[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
w_sheet.write(12,10, str(t1cell17[0].text), style)
a5 = str(t1cell17[0].text.encode('utf-8'))

#Sabado 7h40min - 8h30min
cell = cells[8]
t1cell18 = cell.paragraphs
a6 = str(t1cell18[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

Fazendo assim:

```
#row cell fixa para o horario
rows = ts[1].rows
cells = rows[1].cells

i = 3
j = 8
k = 1

while (i < 9):
    cell = cells[(i)]
    item = cell.paragraphs
    item = str(item[0].text.encode("utf-8"))
    item = unicode(item, "utf-8")
    i = i+1

    while (j < 13):
        w_sheet.write((j),10, item, style)
        j = j+1

        while (k < 7):
            a(k) = item
            k = k+1
```

porem na parte final do while onde tento colocar a(k), não esta funcionando precisava que a cada lopping do ultimo while me retornasse:
a1 = item
a2 = item
.
.
.

Se tiverem outra opção de solução também pode compartilhar.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns probleminhas.

Por exemplo:

```
while (i < 9):
```

Estes parênteses não são necessários.

Estes também não:

```
cell = cells[(i)]
```

Não entendi o que quer dizer isso:

```
a(k) = item
```

Acho que `a` é algo como um dicionário, então na verdade seria assim:

```
a[k] = item
```

O código final ficou assim:

```
#row cell fixa para o horario
rows = ts[1].rows
cells = rows[1].cells
a = {}

i = 3
j = 8
k = 1

while i < 9:
    cell = cells[i]
    item = cell.paragraphs
    item = str(item[0].text.encode("utf-8"))
    item = unicode(item, "utf-8")
    i += 1

    while j < 13:
        w_sheet.write(j, 10, item, style)
        j += 1

        while k < 7:
            a[k] = item
            k = k+1
```

Comment: Acho que com `a(k) = item` ele está a tentar criar um dicionário mesmo. Era o que ia responder como solução! +1

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta tão rápida =D
no a(k) não sei te dizer se é um dicionário.
depois vou precisar usar da seguinte forma
manhasegunda = (a1, a7, a13, a19, a25, a31)
assim tenho retorno que a variavel a1 não é definida.
Obs eu tinha tentado dessa forma tbm =D

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo aqui...
mudei um pouco, de qualquer forma muito obrigado =D

```
#row cell fixa para o horario
rows = ts[1].rows
cells = rows[1].cells

    a = {}

    i = 3
    j = 8
    k = 1

    while k < 7:
        cell = cells[k+2]
        item = cell.paragraphs
        item = str(item[0].text.encode("utf-8"))
        item = unicode(item, "utf-8")
        w_sheet.write(k+7, 10, item, style)
        a[k] = item
        k += 1
```

Colocando em um array assim:

```
manhasegunda = (a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6])
```